# jQuery ajax with non 200 responses

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do I make success* fire for all status codes?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/"
    , dataType: 'json'
    , type: 'POST'
    success: function (data) {
        alert('all good');
    }
});
```

`*` note i don't care if its the "success" method that fires, i just want to have the response entity parsed as JSON.

My response entity for a `400` might be some JSON with the details as to why it was a bad request, is there some setting to make this work out of the box with jQuery? Or do I have to hand roll this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `complete: function () { }`, instead of `success`.  In this case, the resulting data won't be parsed by jQuery, but you can do that yourself by performing `$.parseJSON()` on the XHR object's `responseText`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/"
    , dataType: 'json'
    , type: 'POST'
    complete: function (xhrObj) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(xhrObj.responseText || "");
        alert('all good');
    }
});
```

Comment: the `complete` callback doesnt get passed the data parameter though. Do i have to then manually parse the response entity from the xhr object?

Comment: @Andrew: was just adding that - yes, you do.

Comment: If a 400 is returned, in FF 3.6 the xhrObj.responseText is empty (even if there is a response body). However if you change the response code to 200, it is populated. This answer does work for chrome however.

Comment: @rynop: are you sure about that? I don't have Firefox on hand to test but it seems like an odd bug to be in a browser where XHR was fairly mature.